# C# won't .show() a form already created

Tags: c#, forms

Trying to have C# show a 2nd form that is already created.  If I create a new one like this it will show it:

```
        Form bottomForm = new Form();
        bottomForm.Show();
```

However my pre-created form will not give the option for .Show()
(The form was created through 'Project -> Add Windows Form')

Any help would be great.

Comment: Welcome to [so], great to see a well written first question +1

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

creating instance of Form2 and calling ShowDialog() method to show it. Use `ShowDialog()` instead of `show()`

```
 Form2 form2= new Form2();
 form2.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: +1 so Christian understands, the form he created via 'Project -> Add Windows Form' would be named `Form2`

Comment: Why ShowDialog instead of Show.

Comment: @JeremyThompson Why the user would not see the form? The form will remain open.

Comment: @MD.Unicorn You're right but the users wont have access to programmatically do anything with the `form2` variable if its scope is local. For this question I think `ShowDialog()` is still just as valid. Thanks for correcting me:)